# PHP facebook popup close

Tags: php, facebook

My script opens popup and logs user, but I want to close window after the login. Now question, how?

```
function login_url()
    {
        $facebook=$this->fb_session;

        echo '<a href="#" onclick="window.open(\''.$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('display' => 'popup')).'\', \'Facebook\', \'height=400,width=600\');"></a>';

    }
```

I can't use JavaScript SDK. I tested this library. JavaScript closes windows after log.

Comment: Put a `redirect_uri` into the login URL, that redirects back to a page of yours inside the popup, that contains not much more then the JS code to close it …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple snippet of JS for this issue

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    opener.location.reload();
    window.close();
</script>
```